# Ordering multiple RouterFunctions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, routes, spring-webflux

I have multiple `RouterFunctions` which I register as beans (one per section of code).

One of them is `/**` for dynamic routing for React. Basically, if no other route matches, I want it to go to that one.

The problem is sometimes, depending on the whims of what order they are used, the `/**` will block another endpoint.

Is there a way to order the separate `RouterFunctions` or a better way to deal with having everything that doesn't match something else go to a specific route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring WebFlux is gathering all RouterFunction beans and reducing them into one using `RouterFunction::andOther` (See [`RouterFunctionMapping`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/40efcc9/spring-webflux/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/support/RouterFunctionMapping.java#L109)).

So you can just order your `RouterFunction` beans as regular beans and Spring WebFlux will do the rest.

```
@Bean
@Order(1)
public RouterFunction first() {
  //
}

@Bean
@Order(2)
public RouterFunction second() {
  //
}

@Bean
@Order(3)
public RouterFunction third() {
  //
}
```

Comment: Does `@Order` require them to all be labeled, or can I just label one with `@Order(100)` and leave the rest to go to whatever (less than 100)?

Comment: I checked it out. Unfortunately, `@Order` defaults to the lowest possible value, so I can't just set the one. However, I can just do `@Order(0)` on the others. Still a better solution than mine though. Thanks.

Comment: you can make specific beans that implement the `Ordered` interface as well, if you're looking for a less declarative way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out a solution that takes advantage of the fact that `RouterFunction` has an `add()` function to combine them together.

First, I had `RouterFunction` beans that looked something like this:

```
@Configuration
class MyRouter {
  @Bean
  fun myRoutes(myHandler: MyHandler): RouterFunction<ServerResponse>
    = router {
      GET("/path", myHandler::handlePath)
    }
}
```

I had multiple of these, and if there were some conflicting paths (like `/**`), which one ran was kind of question mark.

I decided to merge these into one `RouterFunction` where I could control the order. Since I didn't want to have to manually manage these somewhere (i.e., if I made a new Router class, I just wanted it picked up automatically).

First, I had to make my normal routes no longer beans. I also needed an easy way to let Spring find them all, so I decided to create an `abstract class` for them to extend.

That looked like this:

```
abstract class RouterConfig {
  open val priority: Int = 0 // higher number, later in list

  open val routes: RouterFunction<ServerResponse>
    get() = TODO()
}
```

The `priority` lets me override the order they are added (with the default being fine if it doesn't matter). A larger number means it'll be loaded later.

After that, I changed my Router classes to `Components` and made them not spit out a bean anymore. Something like this:

```
@Configuration
  class MyRouter(
    private val myHandler: MyHandler
  ) {
    override val routes: RouterFunction<ServerResponse>
      get() = router {
        GET("/path", myHandler::handlePath)
      }
}
```

Finally, I create a new class and bean which would gather them all up:

```
@Configuration
class AppRouter {
  @Bean
  fun appRoutes(routerConfigs: List<RouterConfig>): RouterFunction<ServerResponse>
    = routerConfigs.sortedBy { it.priority }
      .map { it.routes }
      .reduce { r, c -> r.add(c) }
}
```

And that seemed to do the trick. Now the routes will be added in priority order, so for the one that might be a bit greedy (`/**`) I simply set the priority of that class to `100` to make it come last.

Comment: check out my answer, your implementation is reinventing beans ordering.